# Spring rabbitmq task queue concurrency

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a task queue which is using a proxy to make http requests. The proxy is limited to 10 concurrent threads / connections. I don't have access to the logs of the proxy.

I am using the following code, and this is making requests on two threads named `ntContainer#1-1` and `container1`. This is resulting in many requests that error due to using too many connections to the proxy.

Is the listener only using 1 default thread and the extra container thread or is there more going on behind the scenes with spring/rabbitmq?
Also how can I debug this further?

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    public final static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "my-tx";
    public final static String MY_PRODUCT_ROUTING_KEY = "my-product-routing-key";
    public final static String MY_PRODUCT_QUEUE = "my-product";

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange topicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue myProductQueue() {
        return new Queue(MY_PRODUCT_QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding myProductBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(myProductQueue()).to(topicExchange()).with(MY_PRODUCT_ROUTING_KEY);
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(MY_PRODUCT_QUEUE);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter);
        container.setPrefetchCount(1);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter(MyListener myListener) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(myListener, "process");
    }
}
```

// listener

```
@RabbitListener(queues = RabbitMQConfig.MY_PRODUCT_QUEUE)
public void process(final Message message) {
    // something like this
    Jsoup.connect(message.getUrl()).proxy().execute()
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the listening is the default for Rabbit MQ which is a fixed thread pool of size 5. I'm guessing that Spring does not change the threading model. For debugging, I would print Thread.currentThread() from my listener.

Comment: With those properties, only one thread will ever call the listener. It's a Spring thread not one of the client threads. Boot default log config truncates the thread name so printing the full thread name will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops; I was looking at the question on my 'phone; I skipped past the container bean; I thought the container bean was a container factory not a container.

You have 2 listener containers -

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = RabbitMQConfig.MY_PRODUCT_QUEUE)
public void process(final Message message) {
    // something like this
    Jsoup.connect(message.getUrl()).proxy().execute()
}
```

The framework will automatically create a container for that listener (it detects the annotation) and you have explicitly declared another container `@Bean`.

> The proxy is limited to 10 concurrent threads / connections.

Even with 2 containers, you'll only get 2 threads, not 10.